# How to get my node.js mocha test running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I have developed a service in node.js and looking to create my first ever mocha test for this in a seperate file test.js, so I can run the test like this:

```
mocha test
```

I could not figure out how to get the reference to my app, routes.js:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.post('/*', function (req, res) {
        var schema={
            type: Object,
            "schema":
            {
                "totalRecords": {type:Number}
            }
        };
        var isvalid = require('isvalid');
        var validJson=true;
        isvalid(req.body,schema
            , function(err, validObj) {
                if (!validObj) {
                    validJson = false;
                }
                handleRequest(validJson,res,err,req);
            });
    })
}
```

This is the server.js:

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express = require('express');
var app = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use (function (error, req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    res.status(400);
    res.json({
        "error": "errormsg"
    });
});

// routes ======================================================================
require('./routes.js')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

And finally test.js:

```
"use strict";

var request = require('supertest');
var assert = require('assert');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

describe('testing filter', function() {
    it('should return an error', function (done) {
        request(app)
            .post('/')
            .send({"hh":"ss"})
            .expect(400,{"error": "errormsg"})
            .end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    done(err);
                } else {
                    done();
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate file called app.js. The only purpose of this file would be to run the server. You'll also need to export your app object from server.js. So, your server.js would look like this

```
    // set up ======================================================================
var express = require('express');
var app = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use (function (error, req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    res.status(400);
    res.json({
        "error": "errormsg"
    });
});

// routes ======================================================================
require('./routes.js')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

Create a new file called app.js and put this inside of it

```
var app = require('./app');
var port = process.env.port || 8000;

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("App listening on port " + port);
});
```

Now, inside of your test file, import your app as follows

```
var request = require('supertest');
var assert = require('assert');
var app = require('./app.js');
....
```

Note that I assume all your files are in the same directory. If you've put your test file in a different folder then you'll need to give the right path while requiring your app object.

Comment: I just tried this and I get this error when running 'mocha test':Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) 'test.js'

Comment: Where did you put the test file?

Comment: it is all in the same root directory

Comment: sorry wrong dir this is the error: app.listen(port, function() {
    ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'listen'

Comment: Did you export the app object from your previous file before requiring it from the new one?

Comment: I ran all the files as you described above

Comment: There is something wrong with how you are importing your app object. Please recheck your file structure or better yet, update your question with your new files.

Comment: Got it working did not endup using the seperate app.js file . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great. But I'd recommend you use a separate file to run your app now that you've separated your app object. You can easily switch between testing and development that way. Right now your app will start to listen even while you're running your tests. I don't think you would want that to happen. Anyway, good luck.